# Is it possible to register for CKSubscription push notifications without having to ask the user?

Tags: ios, macos, cloudkit, tvos

Currently, you have to have permission for notifications granted by the user:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Is it possible to still get remote notifications for subscriptions without having to ask for permission? My CKSubscription is for a record zone, by the way.

Comment: AFAIK, in iOS 9 (and thus tvOS), you need to ask permission to display notifications to the user, but not to register for remote notifications.

Comment: @jcaron So I need to get rid of the `registerUserNotificationSettings`, part, then? Also...what then for iOS 8?

Comment: Just tested on both 9 and 8, the `registerUserNotificationSettings` part seems to be required :(

Comment: What happens exactly? The documentation for `registerForRemoteNotifications` says "If you want your app’s remote notifications to display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must call the registerUserNotificationSettings: method to request the types of notifications you want to use. If you do not call that method, the system delivers all remote notifications to your app silently."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish there was a way to do this without bugging the user. Especially since even if the user says No, iCloud still gets the needed notifications. So it really is pointless that the alert asks the user.

But the problem is that the calls to `registerForRemoteNotifications` and `registerUserNotificationSettings:` are not specific to iCloud.

I think anyone using CloudKit needs to make an enhancement request to Apple asking for an API that lets an app register for iCloud notifications without the need to prompt the user for permission (whose result is ignored anyway).

To directly answer your question - no, it's not currently possible to register for iCloud notifications without needlessly prompting the user.

Comment: If user says No, the app won't be registered for receiving any notifications, including CKSubscription's ones. That's frustrating..(

Answer (score 3):

Actually, seems like there is a way to receive CKSubscription notes without confusing user asking him to allow these "visible notifications".

To do this you should omit `[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings]` line of code and just call `[application registerForRemoteNotifications]` without any preconfiguration.

Next, to make the app capable of receiving push notes silently, go to your app's Capabilities, activate "Background modes" and check "Remote notifications" option.

Happy coding!

Comment: So the user doesn't need to enable notifications for your app at all for this to work?

Comment: Yes, in this case the app even isn't listed in Notifications section of Settings app.